# Не открываются и не записываются файлы в VS 15/17

Tags: c, файлы

Раньше все было нормально, сейчас не хочет читать и создавать файлы.
Переустановить пробовал, стояла 2015, поставил 2017, все равно не работает :(

В гугле ничего найти не могу, помогите пожалуйста, надо срочно лабу доделать :D

Пример кода:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
FILE *output;

output = fopen("qwerty", "w"); //qwerty.txt так же не работает

if (output) puts("File was created");
else puts("File was not created");

if (output) fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: имеется куча online компиляторов, codeblocks, CodeLite да в конце-то концов запускайте просто через компилятор gcc, конечно у вас не будет такого замечательного дебага, как в вижле, но альтернатив куча

Comment: скорее всего каталог не доступен для записи. Может быть файл открыт кем то уже (блокнотом или антивирусом).

Answer (score -1):

Мдаа, извиняюсь.

Все дело было в антивирусе, почему то не позволял создавать файлы после обновления.
А я уже хотел винду переустанавливать :D